# In mySQL how would I test if NOW() is within an interval leading up into upcoming timestamp and not older than the timestamp?

Tags: mysql, date

For some reason, I cannot wrap my head around the syntax and logic for this problem.

My most recent iteration of the code looks like this.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(start, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) >= NOW();
```

While this is true for the condition if `start+15 mins` is greater than `NOW()` 
it is also true for the condition if `start` is older than `NOW()`. This the part of the code I am having an issue with.

Then I know I can add some operator `AND`, `>=` or, `<=` with respect to an upcoming timestamp called `start` or `NOW()` and also use `DATE_ADD` or `DATE_SUB` but I can not seem to find the correct combination of the above if `NOW()` is within an interval leading up into upcoming timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if we are within 15 minutes of the `start` time (but only if we're *before* the time) this will work:

```
NOW() BETWEEN start - INTERVAL 15 minute AND start
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a quick test and I think this solves it!